# Array Size in Mupad?

Tags: arrays, matlab, size, mupad

It seems much more clearer that be asked; but I could not find it by my first searches.

Does anyone know how to find size of an array in Mupad session of Matlab?

```
M := [12 , 21, 432]:
size(M):
length(M):
```

None of them works well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is nops(M) in mupad

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This seems similar to MATLAB's `numel()`
What about the size of a matrix in more than one dimension, as is given by the MATLAB function `size()`?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: my bad I wasn't able to get it at first attempt, but I accidentally came across the proper method to obtain what OP asked for. The method is:

```
linalg::matdim(A)
```

From manual:

linalg::matdim(A) returns the dimension of the matrix A, i.e., the number of rows and columns of A.